How to Prevent Context Switching in Asycnio
I have this code
class GameMatchesWorker:
    def __init__(
        self,
        consumer: consumers.AbstractConsumer,
        producer: producers.AbstractProducer,
        provider_client: fast_data.FastDataClient,
    ) -> None:
        self._consumer = consumer
        self._producer = producer
        self._provider_client = provider_client
        self._matches = set()
        self._input_buffer = []
        self._input_event = asyncio.Event()
        self._match_schedular = {}
        self._lock = asyncio.Lock()

        async def _receive(self) -> dict:
        while not self._input_buffer:
            await asyncio.wait_for(self._input_event.wait(), timeout=10)
            self._input_event.clear()
        received_data = self._input_buffer.pop(0)

        if received_data.get("code") == fast_data.StatusCodes.SUCCESS:
            return {game_match_meta["game_id"]: game_match_meta for game_match_meta in received_data["list"]}


    async def _get_update_schedule(self):
        current_date = datetime.now()
        for source in range(1,6):
            await self._provider_client.emit_games_list(
                date_from=current_date, date_to=current_date, source=source
            )
            matches_schedule = await self._receive()
            self._match_schedular[source] = matches_schedule

    def _check_match_in_schedule(self, match_id: int):
        for source in self._match_schedular.values():
            if match_id in self._match_schedular[source]:
                return True

    async def _consume_callback(self, game_match_message: consumers.GameMatchMessage) -> None:
        with TRACER.start_as_current_span("fastdata_workerhost_consume_message"):
            game_match_id = game_match_message.game_id
            if not self._check_match_in_schedule(game_match_id):
                await self._get_update_schedule()

When the code execution goes to the self._get_update_schedule() method in the _consume_callback, the execution context switches to the next message, and in this scenario, I need to achieve synchronous execution. Library aio-pika is used
I tried to install asyncio locks. Lock() at different program levels

How is the async _consume_callback called?

I am not familiar with aio-pika and I am not 100% clear on what you are asking but I think you are saying that when _consume_callback is invoked you need to have it complete without another asyncio task running in the same thread getting dispatched, i.e. you don't want the execution of _consume_callback to get suspended.
If that is correct the technique I would use is to create a concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor instance and have _check_match_in_schedule run in the thread pool. Consequently, _consume_callback is not awaiting anything and therefore will not let another async task run and _get_update_schedule will be running in another thread. Not knowing the semantics of I cannot guarantee that running _provider_client.emit_games_list and receive in another thread will not be problematic.
Update
If we cannot assume that we are free to make an async method non-async as suggested by Paul Cornelius, then the following demo program demonstrates the technique:
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)  # Only need a single thread

class MyClass:
    ...


    async def foo(self):
        for source in range(1,6):
            await self.bar()

    async def bar(self):
        print('bar')

    async def foobar(self) -> None:
        # Note that we are not using loop.run_in_executor
        # since that returns a future that must be awaited:
        future = pool.submit(asyncio.run, self.foo())
        result = future.result()


obj = MyClass()
asyncio.run(obj.foobar())

Your code will therefore be:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)  # Only need a single thread

class GameMatchesWorker:
    ...

    async def _consume_callback(self, game_match_message: consumers.GameMatchMessage) -> None:
        with TRACER.start_as_current_span("fastdata_workerhost_consume_message"):
            game_match_id = game_match_message.game_id
            if not self._check_match_in_schedule(game_match_id):
                future = pool.submit(asyncio.run, self._get_update_schedule())
                result = future.result()

I believe this is a simpler solution than Paul Cornelius's as it requires no modification to _get_update_schedule and only a slight change to _consume_callback.

The only comment I have is that your solution creates a new event loop for each call to foobar whereas mine does not.  I don't know how big a performance issue this is, so perhaps it doesn't amount to much.  I completely agree that your solution is simpler.

I realized that. So I did a benchmark where I created a new event loop once and used it N times with loop.run_until_complete to call an async function vs, calling asyncio.run N times and the latter was many times slower (something like a fraction of a second vs. 5 seconds; don't remember the exact numbers). Note that you are calling run_async multiple times in _get_update_schedule whereas I have left _get_update_schedule unchanged and running the entire function in another thread. So I am executing asyncio.run once and you are executing asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe 6 times.

This also means I don't have to worry about the possibility of _get_update_schedule getting modified in the future with additional await statements.

Booboo's answer seems to me completely correct, and should work fine as long as your situation allows you to change the declaration of _get_update_schedule from async def to def.
An alternative is to follow the recipe here:
How to call async function from sync funcion and get result, while a loop is already running
Entering or importing this code gives you a new function, run_async.  You would then modify your method _get_update_schedule:
async def _get_update_schedule(self):
    current_date = datetime.now()
    for source in range(1,6):
        run_async(self._provider_client.emit_games_list(
            date_from=current_date, date_to=current_date, source=source
        ))
        matches_schedule = run_async(self._receive())
        self._match_schedular[source] = matches_schedule

This method remains async but it contains no await expression.  The event loop in this thread is blocked so no other asyncio Task can run.  The async methods _emit_games_list and receive run in a different event loop, in another thread.  This thread waits until they finish.
Note that this approach creates only one new event loop (in the new thread), which is used over and over again.  The asyncio docs imply that creating a new event loop is fairly expensive so it should be avoided if possible.
This approach comes with exact the same disclaimer as Booboo's answer: "Not knowing the semantics I cannot guarantee that running _provider_client.emit_games_list and receive in another thread will not be problematic."

Your answer has motivated me to add an update to my answer to handle the situation where we are stuck with _get_update_schedule needing to remain async. I believe, however, my updated answer to be simpler. Take a look if you care to. Meanwhile, I will upvote your answer.
